# (partial apply str) and apply-str in clojure's ->

Tags: variables, clojure, partial

If I do the following:

```
user=> (-> ["1" "2"] (partial apply str)) 
#<core$partial__5034$fn__5040 clojure.core$partial__5034$fn__5040@d4dd758>
```

...I get a partial function back.  However, if I bind it to a variable:

```
user=> (def apply-str (partial apply str))
#'user/apply-str
user=> (-> ["1" "2" "3"] apply-str)       
"123"
```

...the code works as I intended it.  I would assume that they are the same thing, but apparently that isn't the case.  Can someone explain why this is to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-> is a macro, so it doesn't have to follow the rules you would expect in terms of application. The macro transforms the source before the forms are evaluated. Try macroexpanding the forms:

```
user> (macroexpand '(-> ["1" "2"] (partial apply str)))
(partial ["1" "2"] apply str)
```

What are you trying to achieve here by using the '->' macro?

EDIT: Note that:

```
user> ((partial apply str) ["1" "2"])
"12"
```

Comment: The code that I'm trying to write is somewhat more complex than that.  This is just a simplified example.  I just want to get a better understanding of how the `->` macro works.  :-)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Anyway, you see what's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do that at all.

```
(->> ["1" "2" "3"] (apply str))
```

Why not do that instead?

Answer (score 4):

The first expression, `(-> ["1" "2"] (partial apply str))`, expands into:

`(partial ["1" "2"] apply str)` which basically means:

Create a function from `["1" "2"]` (which is also a function, since vectors are functions of index keys!) with the Vars `apply` and `str` already supplied as the first two arguments. This function gets printed as the weird `#<core$partial...>` string.
Only when this function will be called will you get an IllegalArgumentException since vectors only take one integer argument, not two Var arguments.

Comment: please note that Clojure being dynamic the fact that vectors are functions doesn't matter for this bug. (partial "hello" "world") returns a function too -- a function which always throws though.

Answer (score 1):

The Macro **->** Threads the expr through the forms as second argument. In your case ends up in  expanding to: `(partial ["1" "2"] apply str)`, creating a parital function based on vector.

But you want to **invoke** a parital function based on apply and str on the threaded expr and thus need:

```
(-> ["1" "2"] ((partial apply str)))
```

Well: this code i quite confusing and not idiomatic Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` macro adds parens around `apply-str` in your second version, that's why the macro expands to code that ends up calling your function.  Look at the source code for `->` and you can see:

```
(defmacro ->
  "Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
  second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
  list already. If there are more forms, inserts the first form as the
  second item in second form, etc."
  ([x] x)
  ([x form] (if (seq? form)
              (with-meta `(~(first form) ~x ~@(next form)) (meta form))
              (list form x)))
  ([x form & more] `(-> (-> ~x ~form) ~@more)))
```

The relevant part is when it's dealing with two arguments, `x` and `form`.  If `form` is a seq, `x` is inserted as the second argument in that list.  Otherwise, the macro puts `form` and `x` it into a list itself.  This is so you can use a bare symbol as shorthand for a list containing one symbol.

```
user> (macroexpand '(-> 123 (foo)))
(foo 123)
user> (macroexpand '(-> 123 foo))
(foo 123)
```